# How do I fetch user's Google Calendar persistently with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

My app already fetches Google Calendar but users has to login every time to get the new calendar. The issue raises from token being expired after a while.

I've already tried the following which is to include user.profile scope:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_APP_KEY, GOOGLE_APP_SECRET, {
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
redirect_uri: GOOGLE_APP_CALLBACK_URL
```

}
    end

So, now the token persist so user doesn't have to login every single time to the app, but if the Google Calendar has new entry, my web app won't be able to fetch the new events because the token is expired.

What's the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete answer, but I was working on similar functionality and found some documentation on using a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

I also found an example of using that token to get a new access token [here](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/12)

the relevant code is:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
        "code", "secret",
        :site => "https://accounts.google.com",
        :token_url => "/o/oauth2/token",
        :authorize_url => "/o/oauth2/auth")
    access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(client,
        {:refresh_token => current_user.refreshtoken})
    access_token = access_token.refresh!
```

I believe you'll need to request an `approval_prompt` of `offline` for the refresh token